# Tension between the dependency inversion principle and avoiding "new" in C++?

Tags: c++, memory, solid

I have seen a lot of advice that it is better to do `Type object;` than

```
Type* object = new Type();
```

in C++ whenever possible—i.e., *minimize your use of `new`*. I understand the rational behind this and appreciate it.

But according to my understanding, to practice dependency inversion requires pointers, e.g.:

```
Type* object = new Implementation();
```

where `Type` is abstract (i.e. contains at least one pure virtual method) and `Implementation` is concrete. It is not possible to do

```
Type object = Implementation();
```

because what that means is

```
Type object;
object = Implementation();
```

which requires constructing `object` as a `Type` initially—but that cannot be done, since `Type` is abstract.

Is there an inherent tension between the dependency inversion principle and avoiding `new` when using C++? If so, what patterns/principles/practices can be used to mitigate this tension?

Comment: Python is my mother tongue; memory management is a language feature from another continent. ;)

Comment: I know the feeling. What you're saying doesn't make sense to me though because to me the Dependency Inversion Principle is about relying on abstracts not concretions which regards use of interfaces/abstract classes/contracts in whichever form your language supports them. I don't know C++ but I'm not inclinced to think a pointer to a class makes it an "abstraction" so much as it makes it a reference which might be shared.

Comment: @JimmyHoffa I am no C++ guru (yet--working on it little by little), but here's my understanding. The only way I know of to do it without a pointer is `Type object = Implementation()`. Counterintuitively, C++ tries to create an object of type `Type`, assigns it to `object`, creates an anonymous object of type `Implementation`, and calls `object`'s copy constructor on it. This fails if `Type` is abstract, however. That is why I do not know a way around pointers. I certainly see why this doesn't make sense to you, though!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can absolutely use Dependency Injection without ever using `new()`.  Polymorphism, which is what you're talking about here, is realized in C++ using pointers and/or references.  Doc Brown already addressed references, let's talk about pointers.

As an example (assuming that `Implementation` is derived from `Type`, and `Bar`'s constructor takes a pointer to a `Type`):

```
Implementation imp;
Bar bar(&imp);
```

The "address of" operator (`&`) takes the address of an object, the result is a pointer to the object.  This is a different way of getting a pointer to an object (different compared to your use of `new`, that is.)

In C++, any time I have a pointer to a `Derived`, I can also use it as a pointer to a `Base`.  That's the whole idea of polymorphism, a `Derived` is a `Base`, right?

If my 2-step example above made a leap that you couldn't follow, I'll repeat it here, but with one more (unnecessary) step:

```
Implementation imp;
Type *t = &imp;
Bar bar(t);
```

`t` is a pointer to a `Type`, so it can point to any class derived from `Type`, including `Implementation`.  No use of `new`.  No tension.

Comment: +1 for getting it right that "dependency inversion" was only a red herring and the real question was only "how do pointers work in C++"

Comment: @DocBrown But what about the factory method pattern? That is a stock way of performing dependency injection, useful for creating fakes for testing, such as you discussed in your answer. Returning a reference to an object allocated on the stack is unsafe, so is that not an example in which `new` must be employed for proper dependency inversion? I really wasn't asking about how pointers work, though an elucidation of that has been helpful. It still seems there is some tension between *avoid `new`* and DIP.

Comment: @Kazark: The method described here can (AIUI) only be used to inject dependencies down the stack. But that actually fits the typical pattern of dependency injection, where some top level code makes decisions about what objects to construct, and then injects them into each other.

Comment: It can be used to create a sort of factory pattern if the alleged factory just returns a pointer to an object which was created earlier by the top level code. So, less of a factory and more of a warehouse, as the top level is creating it, then leaving it there.

Comment: I'm getting a warning something like `warning: taking address of local variable`. I found I could get around this like this: `const Type& t = Implementation(); Bar bar((Type*)&t)`, but that is *very* messy compared to `Type* t = new Implementation(); Bar bar(t); delete t`. I also do not want to be getting any compiler warnings. It's still looks like there is a tension between "avoid new" and the DIP, and I'm inclined to fudge on the "avoid new" rather than the DIP.

Answer (score 8):

DIP means instead of instantiating objects of class `Foo` directly in class `Bar`, you have an abstract interface `IFoo`, and pass already constructed objects of type `IFoo` into `Bar` (for example, through the constructor of `Bar`). That allows you easily to replace `Foo` objects in `Bar` by `MockFoo` objects for example, for testing purposes. If those objects are constructed on the stack like

```
 Foo foo;
 Bar bar(&foo);
```

or dynamically like

```
 IFoo *foo = new Foo();
 Bar bar(foo);
```

where `Bar` constructor has the signature

```
  Bar(IFoo *foo)
  {
       //...
  }
```

does not matter in terms of DIP, that decision does only depend on the intended life time of your object `foo` (which in both cases should be at least as long as the lifetime of `bar`).

The pointer variant is technically different on one aspect: if you like, you can transfer the ownership of the `foo` object to `bar` and let `bar` do the memory cleanup by calling `delete` on `foo`in the destructor. However, it is questionable if this is good programming style, and I would not recommend that technique to you. If you want to have automatic cleanup of `foo` when bar does not need it any more, I suggest that you better make use of smart pointers.

To your edit: I guess you have a misconception here about pointers and "new". This code

```
 Implementation object;
 Type *ptrObject = &object;
```

gives you a pointer to an object of type `Type` without using `new`. Or in short:

```
"Avoiding the usage of new" != "You cannot have pointers"
```

(and both is irrelevant to the dependency inversion principle).

Comment: @Kazark: my first two code lines in the DIP example above don't use `new`, didn't you notice? See my edit.

Comment: Okay, I did, but I didn't follow that you were actually still using dependency inversion—sorry. Thanks! +1

Answer (score 0):

No, dependency inversion does not necessitate pointers.

The decision to use pointers or not is a question of data sharing and memory optimization.

Dependency inversion has to do with class hierarchies and inhertiance.

All the same places where you expect to pass `Type*` that was allocated with `new Type()` can be changed to accept a `Type&` that is created with `type = Type()`.

Comment: Ah yes, but what about when I am expected to pass `Type*` and it was allocated with `new Implementation()`? That's what I'm asking. If `Type` is abstract, `Type object = Implementation()` fails.

Comment: Okay, my apologies. I see that I didn't make it very clear that I meant `Type` to be abstract in the question. I have now clarified that in the question.

Comment: @Kazark: It works you just need a reference. `Type& object = Implementation();`

Comment: @LokiAstari It seems that doesn't work, but rather: `const Type& object = Implementation();`. I couldn't get it to compile without the `const`, anyway. The sad thing is that then, when I go to use it, I have to cast away the `const`, thus: `(Type*)&object`. The result is very messy.

Comment: @Kazark: That's probably because you returned by value. If you return by reference then no need for the const. Depending on your code returning by value is probably wrong as it would cause object slicing.

Comment: @LokiAstari Good thought, but it was actually a delegated call—I've already read the discussion on S.O. about returning local objects.

Comment: @Kazark: "Delegated Call"? Whats that. My statement stands. It has to be const because you are returning by value. This is more than likely wrong. You should be returning by reference.

Comment: @LokiAstari What I meant by *delegated call* is that I was not returning it. Rather, I was calling another object with it as an argument. The method it was created inside of had a `void` return value, and it was not assigned to a class member but a local variable.

Comment: @Kazark: Same comment applies. You are doing something wrong.